# BotComposer, how to iterate through the characters of a string using lg language?

Tags: botframework

We need to extract a number from a phrase. For example:

"hey, 1234" -> "1234"

"ok, 4567" -> "4567"

"b3456f" -> "3456"

But we don't found how to iterate through a string using only language generator of the Bot Composer.

We try things like:

join(foreach(createArray("ab c"), x, concat(x, '-')), '')

But with no result... is there any prebuild function that converts a simple string on an array of chars, so we can iterate char by char using foreach?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @mdrichardson! Perfect. Until we don’t have this enhancement (able to create an array of chars from a string) we are using a mix solution: 1) In Composer, certainly we use split by space to get an array of words for iterate on it and then we only join all words that match an “eight digits word” like “[0-9]{8}”. For example, for: “let’s go,12345678” > [ “let’s”, “go,”, “12345678” ] > “12345678”. For the case of “ a12345678b”, we don’t cast this as int, 2) we call an API Controller that receives “a12345678b” and in .Net Core 2.2, we parse that text to only have digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this currently isn't possible as there's no way to iterate over a string or split a string into a new array by character. [I've opened a GitHub issue to request it as an enhancement](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/3279).

For:

- "hey, 1234" -> "1234"
- "ok, 4567" -> "4567"

You can use [`split()`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/common-expression-language/prebuilt-functions.md#split).

Unfortunately, you're out of luck for your "b3456f" -> "3456" example, unless you know it's going to come in that exact format, in which case, you could use [`substring()`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/common-expression-language/prebuilt-functions.md#substring).

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe look into using a Regex to do this, if you know the formats will be pretty controlled, but another option is to look at the [LUIS](https://www.luis.ai/) language understanding services from Microsoft, which are built exactly for understanding different parts of a text message, especially in a bot context. Here's a link to [getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-csharp-tutorial-bf-v4) with this, for C# (on the menu just below in this link, is a Node example if that's what you need).

There's also a [tag here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/luis) focused just on LUIS, if you run into trouble or need any more help.

Hope that helps

[Update] I re-read your question and I see now it's about BotComposer, not a custom developed bot. As a result, the sample I linked to is not valid, but LUIS certainly is. I haven't used Bot Composer myself, but LUIS is integrated as part of it - see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/blob/stable/docs/bfcomposer-intro.md#language-understanding).